# Highchart is not working in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Hi I am using highchart API for generating graph in loop

```
 for(i=1;i<10;i++)
                {

            xseries = "{'INCOPAV','B&M','SGS-ETSA'}";
            yseries = "[{name: 'Generados',data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]}, {name: 'Cerrados',data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]}]";

            generateAllGraph('graph_container'+i,'abcd'+i,xseries,yseries);

                }



function generateAllGraph(container,graphTitle,XaxesSeries,YaxesSeries)
{

                     $('#'+container+'').highcharts({
                                chart: {
                           renderTo: container,
                           type: 'column'
                       },
                       title: {
                           text: graphTitle
                       },
                       subtitle: {
                           text: ''
                       },
                       legend: {

                           itemStyle: {
                               fontSize: "10px"

                           }
                       },
                       xAxis: {
                           categories:  [XaxesSeries]

                       },
                   yAxis: {
                       min: 0,
                       title: {
                           text: 'Registros'
                       }
                   },

               tooltip: {
                   formatter: function() {
                       return ''+
                           this.x +': '+ this.y +' Registros';
                   }
               },
               plotOptions: {
                   column: {
                       pointPadding: 0.2,
                       borderWidth: 0
                   }
               },
               series: YaxesSeries
           });
}
```

but it is not taking X and Y axes as per argument

I think there is something wrong in passing X-axes and y-axes variable I tried it with using jQuery.parseJSON( ) but not getting result

and giving output like this

please help me

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all as SteveP said, xseries is not a proper array declaration.

Once you sort that out, you need to get rid of the double quotes around the xseries/yseries.
What you need to do is:

`var json1 = jQuery.parseJSON(xseries);
 var json2 = jQuery.parseJSON(yseries);`

and pass these variables around.

Hope that helps

Comment: I was wrong in JSON format otherwise I used same code before post question and again Its working ....just I need to check JSON format over http://jsonlint.com/ site

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the series as strings, not as objects. Also, the xseries is not a valid array declaraton. Try:

```
xseries = ['INCOPAV','B&M','SGS-ETSA'];
yseries = [
       {name: 'Generados',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]
       },
       {
        name: 'Cerrados',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]
       }
      ];
```

(Note, no double quotes around it.